# Proving that if left coset multiplication is well-defined then $H$ is a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am given the left coset multiplication rule which is :

$$aHbH=abH$$

Taking representatives $x \in aH $ and $a^{-1} \in a^{-1}H$ 
$$xHa^{-1}H=xa^{-1}H$$

Take representatives $a\in aH$ and $a^{-1}\in a^{-1}H$ Then

$$aHa^{-1}H=H$$

If, multiplication is well defined then, $xa^{-1}H=H \implies xa^{-1}=h \ \ for \ some \ h\in H \implies x=ha \implies aH \subseteq Ha$

Now in order to prove the containment in other direction what should I do? I can easily do the exact same thing, but I'm not given a definition for right coset multiplication - I don't know how to multiply right cosets? Should I act as if I was given the such property? If I should, why? If shouldn't how ?

Comment: You've shown $aHa^{-1}H=H$ and that immediately gives $aHa^{-1}=H$ which is a definition of a subgroup being normal. Or if you prefer $aH=Ha$, you simply postmultiply $a$ to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the definition of a normal subgroup as the kernel of a homomorphism. Then you're told that $\phi: a \mapsto aH$ is a homomorphism (because coset multiplication is well-defined); its kernel is just $H$, so you're done.