# Equivalent Definition for Normal Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H\le G$ then the following holds true:

$H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ iff $\forall g,h\in G$ there is a $k\in G$ such that $gHhH=kH$.

Necessity is trival, but I'm stuck at the other way.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only/14289), or many other ones here at this site for this question. May be, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246177/proving-that-if-left-coset-multiplication-is-well-defined-then-h-is-a-normal-s?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a better duplicate?

Comment: I don't think it is the same. The existing $k$ need not to be $g$ as in your posted threads.

Comment: Trivially $gh=gehe\in gHhH=kH$, so wlog $k=gh$. It's the same question.